# J2ME how to take photo and save it to memory?

Tags: java, java-me

Just take photo and save. I dont need any "Showing the Camera Video" or etc. Because i can't understand anything when there is too much code.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void startPlayer() {
   try {
         Player player = Manager.createPlayer("capture://video");
         player.realize();
         videoControl = (VideoControl)
         player.getControl("VideoControl");
         if (m_objVideoControl != null) 
         {
           form.append((Item) videoControl.initDisplayMode(
           VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, null));
           player.start();
         }
       } catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle it
}

// Use this to take a snapshot
public void commandAction(Command cmd, Displayable d) {
   if ((cmd == snapShotCommand) && d == this) {
    try {
         data =
           videoControl.getSnapshot("encoding=jpeg&width =160&height=120"));
          // videoControl.getSnapshot("encoding=png&width= 80&height=60"));
          // videoControl.getSnapshot("encoding=bmp&width= 160&height=120"));
   } catch (Exception ex) {
     // handle it
   }
}
```

- [Read More](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/picture/)

To store image into DB you can use RMS. [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/how-to-store-retrieve-image-in-from-rms.html) it has explained how